# Formatting XML returned from form POST

Tags: xml, portal

I have a regular HTML page with a form on it.  The form POSTs to a remote server that returns its data in XML.

I want to then transform this data into an easy-to-read format.  How do I go about doing this?  I am willing to try client-side or server-side solutions.  We do our development work using Oracle Portal (yuck), and I am not entirely sure how I can do this using the built-in Portal XML-components, or through a hand-built stored procedure.

This is probably a pretty basic question, but I am fried and can't find anything online that would really help me.

Thanks for your help,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You could try XSLT - xml style sheets, but only if your just trying to change the XML into a similar HTML structure or cut it down, It can get messy quite quickly.

Comment: I do have some familiarity with XSLT, but how do I apply them to the response from the remote server?  I think that is my real question here.  Must that be done server-side?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some JavaScript to dynamically alter the DOM to add newer elements. Or, If you have access to a server runtime, you could catch the POST data yourself, then make a call to the actual backend, then use XSLT in your server program to convert the data before sending it back to the client. All of this assuming that you have these features in your server runtime.